# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing of "nice" URLs not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

In my `RouteConfig` I have the following

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Inbox", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

So I would expect an URL like this to work.

In my `ActivityController` I have an Index Method accepting an integer as parameter. I expect an URL like `localhost/activity/1234` to call the Index method of the of the activity controller. However I am getting an error saying that the required int parameter is null
If I change the URL to:  `localhost/activity/?param=1234` it is working. Is there any way I could make it work without the parameter name?

Comment: Looks like your Index method on ActivityController accepts a parameter named `param`, not `id`

Comment: Yes.I thought that {id} is a placeholder for any parameter but it seems like the name matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Parameter name must be named id for the default route to work